# Emacs org mode: tables aligning emali, fixed-width font, html email

Tags: html, css, fonts, html-email, org-mode

If I send per email something like:

```
| Name  | Phone | Age |
|-------+-------+-----|
| Peter Pl. |  7366334 |  17 |
| Anna S.  |  373734321 |  25 |
```

It will look broken with a variable width font, but OK with a fixed-width font. What can I do to force the font on the recipient?

Comment: try this font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

Comment: @Fags: these are not fixed-width. Besides that, my question was about how to force the font.

Comment: If you are sending it to someone you can force the font for, you are likely sending it to someone that takes html.  Would it be ok to wrap it in a <pre>?

Comment: @JoshBerry: the <pre> tag works quite well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending html email, this seems a clear case for the `<pre>` tag.

(Amusingly, even works here.)

```
| Name      | Phone     | Age |
|-----------+-----------+-----|
| Peter Pl. |   7366334 |  17 |
| Anna S.   | 373734321 |  25 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the font-family CSS property to specify first your preferred monospace fonts, then the generic monospace keyword (in case your first choice of font isn't installed by the recipient).

e.g.

```
body {
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
}
```

Remember that fonts with names containing spaces need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS:

```
<div style="font-family:'Courier New'">
     <!-- Table goes here -->
</div>
```